# VIM: How to open a file in current split view

Tags: vim

With vim opened already and the current view has been (vertically) split, if the cursor is in the right view, how to open a file in the right view.

I tried to use "e filename", which opened the file, and swapped the left and right views, i.e., the file was opened in the left view and the content in the left view was swapped to the right.

Comment: Are you using any special vim configuration? Normally, `:e` opens in the window where the cursor is.

Comment: Yup, after saw the answer. I have found the culprit plugin in my configuration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to vi.stackexchange

Answer (score 6):

`:e filename` open file in the view where cursor current in.

Comment: Thanks. I tested vim -u NONE, confirming your answer. After, found the culprit plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to swap between left and right views after the file open do the below commands:

```
<ctrl-w><r>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:vsp <filename>` will open a file vertically in left window and move the existing file to the right window.